# Is there a way to update a document when date is expired in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I have read some solutions and wonder if I can update (not delete) a document in mongodb if the date is expired after 2 days. Like this.

```
date:2019-02-15
status:not expired
```

After 2 days update the status into `expired`. Here is my code for posting a document.

```
var bloodstock = new Bloodstock(); 
bloodstock.date = new Date();
bloodstock.status = "not expired"; 
bloodstock.save(function(err) {});
```

Comment: There is currently no facility to do this from MongoDB itself. TTL index was used to delete, but not update documents. Currently as of MongoDB 4.0.6, you would need to setup a separate cron job (e.g. nightly) to mass-update documents older than a specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) at daily midnight to compare the date. If the date exists 2 days update the status on the database.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob('00 00 00 * * *', function () {
    if (Date.parse(today_date) > Date.parse(new Date(db_date).getTime() + (2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))) {
        //Update your status
        ...
    }
});
job.start();
```

*Note : Date comparison can be done either on the MongoDB query or Javascript,It depends on the size of document you need to update.*

Comment: im not familiar with this, but how about for 60 secs expiration how can i implement it

Comment: Cron can be run even for every 1sec, You can also use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for 60sec from the time of creation